# IE9 text rendering issue - tails on letters cut off

Tags: css, fonts, internet-explorer-9, typography

I'm running into an issue where - in IE9 standards mode - IE9 renders text in such a way that the tails on descending letters - "q, p, y" etc - disappear. Have tried playing with padding and other common CSS settings in helps of fixing this but am having no luck so far.

Who's got an idea what this might be?

Comment: Are you designing a page or just viewing someone else's page?

Comment: What's the `line-height` and do you have an example online?

Comment: The best solution I could find for this is to use box-sizing (in all its many-splendored vendor-prefixed forms) and setting it to content-box, which seems to best mimic what IE7 does with the box model.

This is the second time I've saved myself from doing browser sniffing by using box-sizing, I highly recommend you look into it if you find yourself in a similar situation in the future!

Comment: @thynctank, @jeroen is on to it. `line-height` is an often overlooked and likely culprit for this error because most browsers ignore it if the height of the element is bigger than the font size.

Comment: height/line-height, padding, etc were all among the first things I went for. No example online just yet, that I can remember how to reach anyway. Thanks for the super quick responses!

Comment: Is it rendering correctly in the modern browsers?

Answer (score 13):

**EDIT:** I found this on a blog. The link isn't live anymore. Leaving it  [here](http://lund.tumblr.com/post/18898252645/line-height-on-input-type-text-in-ie9) just in case it pops up again.

> Its as though the text is a node inside the input and the line-height
>   has been set on that inner element, with the surrounding element
>   clipping the overflowing text.
>
> The solution is simple, set the line-height to be “1” (no-units)

Comment: This solved my issue. I found some posts that mention something about the DOCTYPE tag related with this, but it didn't work in my case.

Comment: Link is broken. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I encountered similar problem in IE11. In ASP.NET classic, textarea is automatically generated with 'cols=20' and 'rows=2' attributes (if not set explicitly in aspx). By applying custom css height and width properties I observed the same text clipping/rendering issue but only when the page was loaded first-time (the attributes setup somehow conflicted with css). When user  manipulated the text in textarea or resized the element, content was re-rendered fine. Turned out, it was indeed the 'line-height' causing this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a custom font (@font-face) as i found that sometimes when using that on certain sizes it would cut off the tails on text, regardless of line-height

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem using `font: inherit` on `input`. Declared the actual fonts I wanted (Verdana primarily) and the tails are visible again.

Also tested `line-height` on `input`—but that caused the problem again.

This is what I ended up with:

```
body, button, input, select, textarea {
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
}
body {
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This setting the line-height:inherit on input boxes did the trick for me.

```
input[type="text"], input[type="email"], input[type="password"], {
  line-height: inherit; /* for i.e. */
}
```