# HTML input (type="search") text being truncated from below in IE10 only

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

This is happening in IE10 only. I have an HTML input tag as 
    `<input type="search" placeholder="Demo text">`
and in IE10 it's truncating the text from below. I am using line-height as 1.45em which is good enough but still getting the issue.

See 'q' and 'g' in the image below.

Image link is below as I can't post the image as I don't have enough points on Stackoverflow.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/otHed.png]

Comment: Have you tried to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/12881956/1662973

Comment: Yes, I tried all the solutions but unfortunately none worked for me.

Comment: What about forcing the document mode in the headers?

Answer (score 0):

By setting min-height fixed my issue. Thanks for your help.